# How to Know whether Push Notification Delivered or not to an iOS app using Pushsharp?

Tags: ios, push-notification, pushsharp

I'm able to Send Push Notification to an iOS app using PushSharp. But I'm not able to receive delivery Status of that Notification to the recipient. How to know the Delivery Status of Push Notification like whatsapp.

Comment: Delivery of push notifications is not guaranteed and there is no feedback that a push has been delivered. If you use a silent push then your app can notify your server when it has received the push

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APNS will not provide any Feedback for Push Notification. So we need to use a Silent Push Notification by make use of content-available property in aps dictionary. As we require a Normal Notification, we must put alert, sound, or badge payload in the aps dictionary. So that The Push Notification will visible to the User. As we are using content-available property in payload, iOS wakes up our app in the background so that we can send Delivery Report to our Web Server.

Sample Payload:

```
    {
        "aps" : {
            "alert" : "Sample Push Notification.",
            "badge" : 2,
            "sound" : "sound.aiff"
            "content-available" : "1"
        }
    }
```